# jQuery -- blockUI is not a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have the following jQuery code that is giving me a problem.  I have two jQuery functions that both call blockUI, and I get the same error for both.  It says that blockUI is not a function.  Can anybody tell me why?

```
function loading() {
                // register on click event for buttons.
                $.blockUI({
                    message: '<h3 class="fldHead">Loading... <img src="/app/images/winliveprog.gif"/></h3>'
                });
                $('body').css('cursor', 'wait');
        }
        $(function() {
            $('[name="btnPreviewPost"]').click(function() {
                console.log('btnPreviewPost clicked');
                $(this).blockUI();
                loading();
                $.blockUI({
                    message: '<h3 class="fldHead">Loading... <img src="/capserver/images/winliveprog.gif"/></h3>'
                });
                $('body').css('cursor', 'wait');
            });
            $('[name="btnEditPost"]').click(function() {
                console.log('btnEditPost clicked')
                $(this).blockUI();
                loading();
                $.blockUI({
                    message: '<h3 class="fldHead">Loading... <img src="/capserver/images/winliveprog.gif"/></h3>'
                });
                $('body').css('cursor', 'wait');
          });
        });
```

Comment: use `$.fn.blockUI` if you want to call `$(this).blockUI();` because you are using it as a [jquery plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring)

Comment: Have you included the plugin correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating it as $.fn.blockUI  for calling it on jquery objects like $(this).blockUI();

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, turns out I included the javascript file twice through some dependency. Once I removed one of the javascript files, `blockUI` worked fine.

Comment: which javascript file? file in which you called $.blockUI ?

Answer (score 5):

I occurred the same problem, and I solved it by including this file:

```
<script src="http://malsup.github.io/jquery.blockUI.js">
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that the jQuery BlockUI plug-in will not function "out of the box" in the latest version of jQuery.This is because BlockUI makes use of the jQuery.browser API, which was removed in jQuery 1.9. To get BlockUI working again, you need to use jquery-migrate:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `$(element).block();` 
see here http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/#element

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue and the problem was path I used to register blockUI. In my case src of the of the jquery.blockUI.js in site.master page was wrong. Please check whether your are registering jquery.blockUI.js correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I my case it was old version (2.0.10) of woocommerce plugin - I couldn't update it because it would break some custom functionality - so I had to comment out jQuery lines with .block in write-panels.min.js and writepanel-product-type-variable.php .

Answer (score 0):

I am using the Angular and meeting the same issue here. Inspired by @Robert, I found out there are two references:

> jquery.min.js

in the angular.json. I removed one and it worked.